# Flutter IAP payment verify and consumable items

Tags: go, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, flutter-layout

I have 2 questions about IAP methods on flutter framework:

I) On the flutter side, I used in_app package:

> in_app_purchase: ^0.2.2+3

on the server-side I used Go-lang. How can i make server side verification after payment purchased?

II) I have already created alpha and beta release  (**on Android**); I can see my consumable items (as available) but when I try to buy, it says an item is not available.

All questions are about Android, not for ios. I've searched for a lot of tutorials on the internet but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: You need to add yourself to the testers account. Send the download link from Google Play to your email. Install the application from the link and only then in app purchases will be available